# Error compiling class

Tags: apex, schedulebatch, compile-error

When I save this class I get the following error:

> Compile Error: unexpected token: 'global Class apexclassfirsttimeinmerket implements Database.Batchable' at line 1 column 0

Code:

```
global Class apexclassfirsttimeinmerket implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{


    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    
    {    
        String queryhye= 'SELECT ID,NAME,description FROM Account';
        
        return database.getQueryLocator(queryhye);
        
    }
    
   
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope)
    
        {
        
        System.debug('all reocrds area is null');
        
            for(account a : scope)
            
            {
                System.debug('for loop has started bhai logo');
                
                if(a.description == NULL)
                {
                    a.description='pimple saudagar';
                    
                 }
            }
            
        update scope;
        
        
      }
      
      
   global void finish( Database.BatchableContext BC)
   {
   
       System.debug('all the records area have updated now');
       
     }
     
  }
```

Comment: No idea, works fine for me

Answer (score 4):

According to https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector, your code contains non-breaking spaces that confuse the Apex compiler. (Cutting and pasting code can sometimes pickup unexpected characters.) Re-key the spaces (or run the code through an editor) to remove them and the code should compile.

Comment: Those pesky ZWS characters are always hiding!